# Search file in a directory and replace it with powershell scripting

Tags: powershell

I have two directories A and B. A is having few *.dll files.B is also having *.dll files.
Now I have to pick file from directory A and search in directory B, if found I will replace the file in B  directory with the file in directory A. 
How I can write powershell script for this.

Comment: What is the criteria for replacing the files in B? Same name?

Comment: Please edit the question and paste in the code you are trying to make work, the desired effect, and the current effect with any error messages.

Comment: Yes files having same name should be replaced in B directory..

Answer (score 1):

IMO Replace / xcopy / robocopy will be faster or more efficient.

In powershell there are thousand ways to do it, here is one:

```
$DirA = "C:\Windows\System32\"
$DirB = "Q:\Test\2018\03\31\"
Get-ChildItem -Path $DirA -Filter *.dll |
  Where-Object { Test-Path (Join-Path $DirB $_.Name) } |
    Copy-Item -Destination (Join-Path $DirB $_.Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need powershell for that.

robocopy src dest /XX

will suffice.